# How can I safe to quit self-hosted application (do something before quit)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want the self-hosted ASP.NET Core Application can delay a moment before quit when receive an exit signal.

I have multiple instances of the application behind a load balancing.

By default, if I shutdown an instance, the processing requests will be broken. And in a short time there are some new requests will still send to the offline instance because load balancing have an interval for health check.

So if I can do something before quit:

1. Disable healthcheck first, it will stop new requests from Load Balancing.
2. Continue processing all the requests that already received.

Then, the application can be "safely" quit. It allows an instance to smoothly down and users will not feel it.

So I want if there is an official solution for that, or a best practice.

Comment: What does "smoothly shutdown without being perceived by users" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm sorry for my broken English. By default, if I shutdown an instance, some processing requests will be broken. And in a short time because load balancing have an interval for health check, there are some new requests will still send to the offline instance. It's bad for user experience.

Comment: Are you running this on Linux? And what version of .net core are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> I want the self-hosted ASP.NET Core Application can delay a moment
>   before quit when receive an exit signal.

What is this signal? KILL or TERM?

Lets say that you want to handle TERM signal.

So, if you are using .net Core 1.X, your solution would be something like this.
First, you need to add dependency to your json file

```
"System.Runtime.Loader" : "<version>
```

Then you can handle SIGTERM event bi adding method to an event

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += YourMethodThatWillHandleSignal;
```

For using .NET Core 2.X, there is different solution. You can use `IApplicationLifetime` interface ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).

when you have this, all you can do is this:

```
applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopping"));
applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Stopped"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm confused why there is no "ready-made" solution, I think it's a very general and useful requirement.

Comment: Ready made? I think that this solution is quite nice

Comment: The "ready-made" I talked means a preset (or existing? I'm sorry for my poor English.). Under your guidance, I will register an `applicationLifeTime.ApplicationStopping` to change the health state, and wait all existing inbound requests finished. But these operations are general, I will need them in every project. So that's why I asked "ready-made" solution that provided by aspnet official or third-party.